# Why is scorer import unnecessary for parameter search in scikit-learn?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, python-import

If I want to optimise the regularisation parameter for a logistic regression model (for example) based on area under the ROC curve, I can use `GridSearchCV` for a suitable range of parameters and set `scoring='roc_auc'`.

This can be done using `from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV`, and there is *no need* to include `from sklearn.metrics import roc_auc_score`.

However, if I want to calculate the area under the ROC curve manually for a particular fitted dataset then I do need to include `from sklearn.metrics import roc_auc_score`.

- How does this work? I assume that by importing `GridSearchCV` we are somehow importing `roc_auc_score` behind the scenes? Unfortunately I can't seem to follow this through in the [source code](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/ab9eebfa3a8d276de67b25ce42002a20298998b5/sklearn/model_selection/_search.py#L866) - I'd really appreciate an explanation.
- If this is the case, does it also mean that by importing `GridSearchCV` we end up importing all possible scoring methods behind the scenes?
- Why then can I not use `roc_auc_score` "manually" myself if I have imported `GridSearchCV` only and not `roc_auc_score` itself? Is it not implicitly "there" behind the scenes?

I appreciate this may be a more general question about python importing and not specific to scikit-learn...

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you just need to read up on how Python does modules and imports. https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html `roc_auc_score` may be imported by `GridSearchCV` but it will be local to that, not in the global namespace.

Comment: Thanks for the link - if I am understanding it correctly I think that `roc_auc_score` is probably being imported somehow but not being added to my global symbol table - but would be good to have my understanding confirmed!

Comment: This will make your path to understanding a lot easier: `dir()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GridSearchCV extends BaseSearchCV class. This means that it will be using the [`fit()` function defined in BaseSearchCV](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/ab9eebfa3a8d276de67b25ce42002a20298998b5/sklearn/model_selection/_search.py#L617).

So now as you can see in [source code here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/ab9eebfa3a8d276de67b25ce42002a20298998b5/sklearn/model_selection/_search.py#L617):

```
    ...
    ...
    scorers, self.multimetric_ = _check_multimetric_scoring(
    self.estimator, scoring=self.scoring)
    ...
    ...
```

It checks all the parameters supplied during the construction of GridSearchCV here.
For `'scoring'` param, its calling a method `_check_multimetric_scoring()`. Now on top of this file, you will see many imports.

The method `_check_multimetric_scoring` points to [`scorer.py` file](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/ab9eebfa3a8d276de67b25ce42002a20298998b5/sklearn/metrics/scorer.py):

Similarly tracing the method calls, we [will reach here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/ab9eebfa3a8d276de67b25ce42002a20298998b5/sklearn/metrics/scorer.py#L499):

```
SCORERS = dict(explained_variance=explained_variance_scorer,
               r2=r2_scorer,
               neg_median_absolute_error=neg_median_absolute_error_scorer,
               neg_mean_absolute_error=neg_mean_absolute_error_scorer,
               neg_mean_squared_error=neg_mean_squared_error_scorer,
               neg_mean_squared_log_error=neg_mean_squared_log_error_scorer,
               accuracy=accuracy_scorer, roc_auc=roc_auc_scorer,
               ...
               ...
 ...
 ...
```

Looking at `roc_auc`, we will [reach here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/ab9eebfa3a8d276de67b25ce42002a20298998b5/sklearn/metrics/scorer.py#L473):

```
roc_auc_scorer = make_scorer(roc_auc_score, greater_is_better=True,
needs_threshold=True)
```

Now look at the parameters here, `roc_auc_score` is sent to `make_scorer`. So from where it is imported? Look at the top of this file and you will see this:

```
from . import (r2_score, median_absolute_error, mean_absolute_error,
               mean_squared_error, mean_squared_log_error, accuracy_score,
               f1_score, roc_auc_score, average_precision_score,
               precision_score, recall_score, log_loss,
               balanced_accuracy_score, explained_variance_score,
               brier_score_loss)
```

So from here, the actual scoring object is returned to the GridSearchCV.

Now, the library is using relative and absolute imports, and as @Denziloe correctly said, those imports are local for that module, not the global imports.

See these answers for more information on import scope and namespaces:

- [Python "import" scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106089/python-import-scope)
- [Python: Namespaces with Module Imports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15890014/python-namespaces-with-module-imports)

And [this python documentation page](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html)

Comment: Thanks - this is very helpful. I assume that when you say "tracing the method calls...", the series of calls you are referring to is `_check_multimetric_scoring` -> `check_scoring` -> `get_scorer` -> `SCORERS`. Also it took me a few minutes to realise that `from . import` can refer to other modules at the same level and that `roc_auc_score` is actually defined in the sibling module `ranking.py` (unless I totally misread the code)

Comment: @Nick Yes, you are correct. Just like linux commands, `from . import` refers to files in same folder, and `from .. import` goes to root level.

Comment: Yes, but actually methods within files in the same folder, which is what caught me out. Actually [note to future readers!] the links you provided to other questions were very helpful as it is not always easy to find this information without knowing the right terms to search on.

Comment: No, I think you got it wrong. I think I explained it wrong. `from . import` will be only successful for imports declared in `__all__` under `_init_.py` file in the folder. All imports made in that file are available directly using `from . import`.

Comment: In the previous comment I was explaining about relative imports of the type: `from .ranking import` and `from ..model_selection import` type of things. Sorry to confuse you.